# JQuery Post And Get

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a method I'm trying to write that can post data to a php file and get the results and return the output in a variable. For some reason, my block of code is not working.

```
function post_get(){

var result = null;

$.post("modules/data.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
function(data){
    result = JSON.parse(data);
}, "json");


return result;
}
```

I get this error when using this method

SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"

Comment: define "not working". Oh wait... its fine, my crystal ball has come back up. I know exactly what your issue is!

Comment: Are you returning valid JSON?

Comment: Watch the request / response on your developer tools to make sure you're getting a return.

Comment: You're returning nothing by the way!

Comment: Assuming you send the correct mime type, jQuery parses the JSON for you and `data` is an JS object. Else, `data` will be a string and `data[0]` the first character of it.

Comment: @Bergi That's only true if you don't specify a `dataType`, which is not the case here

Comment: @Bergi I can see it in their code...it's the 4th parameter in the `post` call

Comment: @Ian: Ah, I'm not familiar with parameters after the callback and overlooked it. But then, `JSON.parse` seems to be invalid (and I hope he did not embed a JSON string in JSON).

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, it's not easy to catch. Haha that's all I can think of being their use case...which is craziness. `JSON.parse` should've been used on the response in the first place behind the scenes, making sure everything inside of `data` is parsed...except for embedded JSON strings. Anyways, if that's not where the problem lies, it must be what the answers are talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server returns proper JSON encoded output and sets the correct headers (`Content-Type: application/json`), you can use `data` immediately:

```
$.post("modules/data.php", {
    "func": "getNameAndTime"
},
function(data){
    console.log(data);
}, "json");

// btw, at this point in the code you won't have access to the return value
```

In fact, even if it didn't return proper data, the `console.log(data)` should provide you with enough information to figure out why it wasn't working in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

1. Ajax is Asynchronous.
2. Is your PHP returning valid JSON?

This is how your code should be written to take advantage of the asynchronous nature of ajax.

```
function post_get(){

    return $.post("modules/data.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" }, "json");

}

post_get().done(function(data){
    // do stuff with data
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(){
    console.log(arguments);
    alert("FAIL.\nCheck the console.");
});
// Do not attempt to bring data from inside the above function to out here.
```

Comment: +1, What about this ? `function post_get(){ $.post("...", {...}, "...").done(function(data){...}); }`, am I Wrong ?

Comment: Yes, that can work too, but it doesn't give outside access to the result.

Comment: @SheikhHeera It's the "same", Kevin B's version just allows more control outside of the function call. It's up to whether you want to be passing callbacks to the function or binding the events yourself

Comment: the return statement will give me something like this

Object
abort: function (statusText) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function (key) {
overrideMimeType: function (type) {
pipe: function () {
progress: function () {
promise: function (obj) {
readyState: 4
responseText: ""STRING""

how do i get the response Text?

Comment: The response text is available inside of the done callback in the variable named `data`. Only inside of the done callback.

Comment: so there is no way to use the response text outside of the done callback?

Comment: well, technically you could use async:false, but that's a TERRIBLE idea (it makes the browser appear to be frozen while the request is being made) and i'm not going to provide an example. Otherwise, no it is not possible to use the response text outside of the done callback.